# connect four: asking for inputs without printing

Tags: python

I am making a connect four type game. I am trying to set up the simple playability of the game. I don't get an error, but it does keep sending me into a input when I want it to print out the board. When I type in a number for the column, it doesn't print anything, it just gives me another input I should fill, this continues until i exit the program.. I am trying to stay away from classes, given that I am not very good at programming these yet. I would like to know why this is happening, and what to do to fix it, or if I just need to reprogram the whole thing.

```
a = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
b = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
c = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
d = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
e = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
f = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
board = [a, b, c, d, e, f] # sets up the board
print("What is player 1's name?")
player1 = input()
print("What is player 2's name?")
player2 = input()
plays = 0


def print_board(): # prints the board
    p = 0
    for x in board:
        for i in x:
            print(i, end=" | ")
        print()
        p += 1
        if p != 6:
            print("- "*15)
        else:
            print()


def win(): # defines a boolean if one player has won
    i = 0
    k = 0
    while i != 5:
        while k != 6:
            if board[i][k] == "o" or board[i][k] == "x":
                if board[i+1][k] == board[i][k] == board[i+2][k] == board[i+3][k]:
                    return False
                elif board[i][k] == board[i][k+1] == board[i][k+2] == board[i][k+3]:
                    return False
                elif board[i][k] == board[i+1][k+1] == board[i+2][k+2] == board[i+3][k+3]:
                    return False
                elif board[i][k] == board[i-1][k-1] == board[i-2][k-2] == board[i-3][k-3]:
                    return False
            else:
                return True


def play(): # defines the part you play.
    if plays % 2 == 0:
        player = "o"
    else:
        player = "x"
    print_board()
    x = int(input("Where would you like to put your chip?"))
    i = 0
    while i < 5:
        if board[i][x] == " ":
            if board[i+1][x] == "x" or board[i+1][x] == "o":
                board[i][x] = player
    print_board()
    if win():
        print(player+" won!")
    play()

play() # runs the script
```

Comment: it is not asking for input, you have an infinite loop, in the while i < 5 - i is never incremented

Comment: actually none of your loops are incrementing the check value, and your run function doesn't need to print the board twice, do the initial print before you call play() then only show it once inside the loop after input

Comment: normally in a game like this the play function would actually be an infinite loop that breaks once the win criteria is met rather than a call of it at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for your play loop - hopefully it will help you fix the win check also:

```
def play(): # defines the part you play.
    plays = 0
    while True:
        if plays % 2 == 0:
            player = "o"
        else:
            player = "x"
        x = int(input("Where would you like to put your chip?"))
        i = 0
        for i in range(5):
            if board[i][x] == " ":
                if board[i+1][x] == "x" or board[i+1][x] == "o":
                    board[i][x] = player
        else:
            board[5][x] = player

        print_board()
        #if win():
        #    print(player+" won!")
        #    break
        plays += 1

print_board()

play() # runs the script
```

i commented out the win check because it doesn't work yet